# $ebp+8 value changes when stack frame is allocated

Tags: assembly, x86, abi

The `sub $0x10, %esp` to allocate the stack frame seems to change the value at `$ebp + 8`.  It changes from `0x...018` to `0x...818`.

```
 (gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function place:
   0x0804b019 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804b01a <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
=> 0x0804b01c <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804b01f <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b022 <+9>: sub    $0x4,%eax
 (gdb) x $ebp+8
0xbfffed70: 0xb6a0c018
 (gdb) si
 (gdb) disas
   0x0804b019 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804b01a <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804b01c <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
=> 0x0804b01f <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b022 <+9>: sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b025 <+12>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
 (gdb) x $ebp+8
0xbfffed70: 0xb6a0c818
 (gdb) x $esp
0xbfffed58: 0xb6a0c018
```

The stack grows to decreasing address (as can be seen from the value of `$esp` vs `$ebp`). So allocating the stack frame is not overriding the value of `$ebp+8`.

What are the possible reasons for this?

Edit: I added watchpoint at 0xbfffed70 (fixed address for $ebp + 8). However, the change in the value at 0xbfffed70 doesn't trigger the watch point.

```
(gdb) si

Hardware watchpoint 12: *0xbfffed70

Old value = 1024
New value = -1230979048
0x0804b21e in mm_malloc (size=2040) at mm.c:380
380    place(bp, asize);
(gdb) si
place (bp=0xb6a0c018, asize=2048) at mm.c:297
297 
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function place:
=> 0x0804b019 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804b01a <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804b01c <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804b01f <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b022 <+9>: sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b025 <+12>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b027 <+14>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b02a <+17>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x0804b02d <+20>:    pushl  0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804b030 <+23>:    call   0x804af5e <remove_free_block>
   0x0804b035 <+28>:    add    $0x4,%esp
   0x0804b038 <+31>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b03b <+34>:    sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b03e <+37>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x0804b041 <+40>:    jbe    0x804b0a5 <place+140>
   0x0804b043 <+42>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b046 <+45>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b049 <+48>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804b04c <+51>:    or     $0x1,%edx
   0x0804b04f <+54>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x0804b051 <+56>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b054 <+59>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b057 <+62>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b059 <+64>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b05c <+67>:    lea    -0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b05f <+70>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b062 <+73>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x0804b064 <+75>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804b067 <+78>:    or     $0x1,%edx
   0x0804b06a <+81>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x0804b06c <+83>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b06f <+86>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b072 <+89>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b074 <+91>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b077 <+94>:    add    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804b07a <+97>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b07d <+100>:   lea    -0x4(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b080 <+103>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b083 <+106>:   sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b086 <+109>:   mov    %eax,(%edx)
   0x0804b088 <+111>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b08b <+114>:   sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b08e <+117>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b090 <+119>:   and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b093 <+122>:   lea    -0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b096 <+125>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b099 <+128>:   add    %eax,%edx
   0x0804b09b <+130>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b09e <+133>:   sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b0a1 <+136>:   mov    %eax,(%edx)
   0x0804b0a3 <+138>:   jmp    0x804b0ce <place+181>
   0x0804b0a5 <+140>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b0a8 <+143>:   sub    $0x4,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
(gdb) si
0x0804b01a  297 
(gdb) si
0x0804b01c  297 
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function place:
   0x0804b019 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804b01a <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
=> 0x0804b01c <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804b01f <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b022 <+9>: sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b025 <+12>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b027 <+14>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b02a <+17>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x0804b02d <+20>:    pushl  0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804b030 <+23>:    call   0x804af5e <remove_free_block>
   0x0804b035 <+28>:    add    $0x4,%esp
   0x0804b038 <+31>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b03b <+34>:    sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b03e <+37>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x0804b041 <+40>:    jbe    0x804b0a5 <place+140>
   0x0804b043 <+42>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b046 <+45>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b049 <+48>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804b04c <+51>:    or     $0x1,%edx
   0x0804b04f <+54>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x0804b051 <+56>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b054 <+59>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b057 <+62>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b059 <+64>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b05c <+67>:    lea    -0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b05f <+70>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b062 <+73>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x0804b064 <+75>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804b067 <+78>:    or     $0x1,%edx
   0x0804b06a <+81>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x0804b06c <+83>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b06f <+86>:    sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b072 <+89>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b074 <+91>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b077 <+94>:    add    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804b07a <+97>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b07d <+100>:   lea    -0x4(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b080 <+103>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b083 <+106>:   sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b086 <+109>:   mov    %eax,(%edx)
   0x0804b088 <+111>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b08b <+114>:   sub    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804b08e <+117>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0804b090 <+119>:   and    $0xfffffff8,%eax
   0x0804b093 <+122>:   lea    -0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x0804b096 <+125>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b099 <+128>:   add    %eax,%edx
   0x0804b09b <+130>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b09e <+133>:   sub    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b0a1 <+136>:   mov    %eax,(%edx)
   0x0804b0a3 <+138>:   jmp    0x804b0ce <place+181>
   0x0804b0a5 <+140>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804b0a8 <+143>:   sub    $0x4,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
(gdb) si

Breakpoint 7, place (bp=0xb6a0c818, asize=2048) at mm.c:298
298    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
(gdb) x $ebp
0xbfffed68: 0xbfffed98
(gdb) x $ebp+8
0xbfffed70: 0xb6a0c818
(gdb) x $ebp+0x8
0xbfffed70: 0xb6a0c818
(gdb) si
0x0804b022  298    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
(gdb) si
0x0804b025  298    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
(gdb)
```

Edit 2: function that exhibits strange behavior

```
static void place(void *bp, size_t asize)
{
    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));

    remove_free_block(bp);

    if ((csize - asize) >= (2 * DSIZE))
    {
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove c tag, this has nothing to do with C. (Even if the assembly originated from a C source file.)

Comment: Please add `display/I $eip` to show instruction being executed and do it again

Comment: so, as I recall AT&T syntax, the `mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax` will move the value located 8 bytes above 'epb' (which will be in the callers stack frame), into 'eax'.  This is one way to pass arguments into the called function.

Comment: @thurizas your answer has nothing to do with the question being asked here.

Comment: Please assert that the program is not multi threaded any maybe one thread runs amok and changes that value.

Comment: @AlexBrown I did as you asked, but It didn't seem to help : (. I can't type out the the command and output here because of word limit, but let me know if you want to see them.

Comment: Put a memory write watchpoint on the given address. PS: you can edit your question, see the [link under the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40877532/edit).

Comment: @BodoThiesen--your correct, I totally misread the question

Comment: @Jester That didn't seem to help either. I posted the result as edit to the original question.

Comment: @BodoThiesen how do I do that ?

Comment: Is the program public? Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: @Jester yes it is available [here](https://github.com/quanvuong/cso-malloc-air-4). Please type in "mdriver -f short1-bal.rep" for the appropriate executable and arguments.

Comment: Works fine here, it doesn't change. Goes twice into `place()` then segfaults :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Jester. Let me try it on a different computer ... Segfault happens because I'm writing to an invalid memory address (that was passed in as a parameter to place() )

Comment: GDB has a text-UI mode that shows a disassembly window and a register window.  Use `layout asm` / `layout reg`.  (See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Your second dump of the `gdb` session doesn't demonstrate the change of the value `$8(%ebp)`, please redo it very carefully and update your post yet again.

Comment: And my comment about multi threading: If your program is single threaded, you can just say so. If it is indeed multi threaded, that is a possible cause (dangling pointers etc) where the value is modified at the point, where `esp` is being changed but the change has nothing to to with that instruction at all, because it happens in a different thread.

Comment: Put on hold? WTF? It's perfectly clear what OP is asking, just not what's causing it.